# Drawing in Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got a simple `Windows.Forms` Form.

I want to fill the `pictureBox1` with color Color.Aqua and draw a rectangle.

However nothing is drown untill I move the Form.

Why is this?

How can I force everything to be drawn without moving the Form?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly Graphics _graphics;
        private List<PointF> _points;
        private Bitmap _bitmap;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 600);
            _graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap);
            pictureBox1.Image = _bitmap;

            var timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 1
            };
            timer.Tick += OnTick;
            timer.Start();
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _graphics.Clear(Color.Aqua);
           _graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 10, 10);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try subscribing to the `Load` `Event` and execute the code in `OnTick()` there.

Comment: Just `Invalidate()` (or better `Refresh()`) picturebox itself (alternatively, if you invalidate `this`, you have to include also its children.) Don't forget to dispose your objects...

Comment: That's a dangerous Timer since it can't be disposed of — move the declaration to the form level.  Don't store that graphic object either.  Create the graphic when you need it, draw with it, then dispose of it.  You are invalidating the form, not the control — use `pictureBox1.Invalidate();`

Comment: Wrong Invalidate() call, use pictureBox1.Invalidate()

Comment: This would work if you reassign the bitma to the PictureBox.Image. But why use the Tick? Do you plan to do more drawing? Do note that the pixels are set and won't be unset, unless you re-create the whole image. In that case why not draw onto the surface in the Paint event, as suggested..

Answer (score 3):

You must subscribe to [Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your picturebox and put your drawing code there,something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Paint += PictureBox1_Paint;
}

private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Aqua);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

This event is raised everytime the control needs to be redrawn, so you don't need that `Timer` trick or calling `Invalidate`

Comment: It works but (and here I am just guessing) OP is trying to do something different (for example to defer an expensive processing into a separate thread/timer) leaving the paint operations pretty fast (because they're just images). I can't see any other reason to use bitmap, graphics and timer together...

Comment: Well @AdrianoRepetti, I think you maybe guessing too much. OP just says _I want to fill the pictureBox1 with color Color.Aqua and draw a rectangle._ What i guess is the timer part and invalidating comes from not nowing about `Paint`event :)

Comment: Usual reason for a timer rather than direct use of `Paint()` event handler is game creation. Timer would be set for 17ms (~60 FPS). Can't do that with just handling items in `pictureBox.Paint()`.

Comment: @CoolBots you are right (although it seems strange create a game that way this days ;) ). But I just sticked to the question _I want to fill the pictureBox1 with color Color.Aqua and draw a rectangle._ Anyway, this is one solution, there are others dealing with the timer.

Comment: Yes, mine was absolutely just speculation. Game? I would not put render logic in a timer. I'm not a game developer but isn't usually a free loop?

Answer (score 1):

I see four problems:

1. The `Invalidate()` method is called for the form. This *should* invalidate the PictureBox, but you can do better by just invalidating the PictureBox directly.
2. You are drawing the bitmap, but not updating the `Image` property of the PictureBox.
3. One millisecond intervals will kill you. 50 to 100 is much more reasonable, and anything less than 17 is probably faster than the refresh rate of your monitor.
4. The whole the thing with the separate graphics is extra and not needed. The pictureBox has it's own graphics context, and you do better using that.

Put it all together, and you get this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private List<PointF> _points;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer = new Timer(100);
        timer.Tick += OnTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Aqua);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to invalidate the picturebox if you are using the `Paint`event?

Comment: @Pikoh, `Invalidate()` raises the `Paint` event. This would work for a game, targeting 60 FPS using a timer, for instance. Otherwise the `pictureBox` would not be repainted at any regular interval.

Comment: Unfortunately using the graphics context from `pictureBox` directly often causes "flicker" if the object of OP's program is a game (which would be run on a 17ms timer; 1ms is actually ignored, WinForms timer can't fire that fast). That's why the `Bitmap` solution is preferred - once rendered to that bitmap, the entire image is set to `pictureBox.Image` property, which OP is not doing (as you pointed out in item #2 in your post).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `Invalidate()` call at all, since you're drawing to a buffer (`Bitmap`). Just set the bitmap to `pictureBox1.Image` property:

```
    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _graphics.Clear(Color.Aqua);
        _graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 10, 10);
        pictureBox1.Image = _bitmap;
    }
```